# Bad answer or Spam?

Tags: discussion

The question [Is SoFi too good to be true?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30657/is-sofi-too-good-to-be-true) has an answer which is currently -5 downvoted, and I've received flags to delete. 
Given the recent discussion of off-topic questions, I am bringing this up here. The answer doesn't address the question. It discusses the company as an investment, not a lender to get a loan *from*. The author includes his reasoning and a link. 
Is this *spam* or just a bad answer left to be downvoted?

Comment: Glad you brought this up. There are quite a few times I am not sure what to do, should I flag or just down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like link farming.

The user's IP links him to {City Deleted} and the page in question is for a company in KC, MO.

I'd vote remove.  If the poster would respond to comments, I'd elect to lecture about quoting relevant parts of the article he likes and citing his source. However the post appears to be a drive by.

Reasons I'd delete:

1. IP match could indicate personal affiliation with linked site
2. Drive by poster not responding to comments
3. Tangentially related answer, indicated link farming
4. No other stack exchange presence
5. Posting referring links in first post is typical bad behavior

Comment: Another alternative would be just to delete the part with the link.

Comment: Note I also 'destroyed' this user. It is obviously some sort of robo spam and has no other positive contribution to this site. Removing the account in this manner feeds into our SpamRam system which will help prevent users like this from creating new accounts in the future.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - I think it would be neat to have a spam eradication league stat.